# PHP & jQuery - Create two different textfields with autocomplete having different lists of data retrieved from the database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, autocomplete

[Customer textfield with autocomplete from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4u8VJ.jpg)

I succeeded to create one Customer textfield with autocomplete to display customers which start by the text being typed.

**index.php** for one textfield

```
              <meta charset="utf-8">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
          <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
          <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
          <script>
          $(function() {
            $( "#customer" ).autocomplete({
                source: "../phpfiles/search.php",
            });
          });
          </script>



        <div class="ui-widget">
        <!-- action='./../customer_report_request' -->
            <form id="customer_report_request" name="customer_report_request" method="post">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan='2'>Search Customer</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Customer: </label>
                            <input name="customer" id="customer" value='' required>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label>Submit: </label>
                            <input value="Send" name="send_customer_request" type="submit" id="send_customer_request">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>

        <?php
            //Display the list of customer details
            if(isset($_POST['send_customer_request']))
            {
                include 'db.php'; //connection

                $query = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE Company_Name = '".$_POST['customer']."'"; 
                $customer_result = $db->query($query);
                $count_customer = $customer_result->num_rows;
                if($count_customer>0)
                {
                    echo"<div>";
                    echo "<table>";
                    echo"<tr>";
                    echo"<th>Company_Name</th>";
                    echo"<th>VAT_Registration</th>";
                    echo"<th>Contact_First_Name</th>";
                    echo"<th>Contact_Last_Name</th>";
                    echo"<th>Email</th>";
                    echo"</tr>";

                    while ($row = $customer_result->fetch_assoc()) 
                    {
                        echo"<tr>";
                        echo"<td>".$row['Company_Name']."</td>";
                        echo"<td>".$row['VAT_Registration']."</td>";
                        echo"<td>".$row['Contact_First_Name']."</td>";
                        echo"<td>".$row['Contact_Last_Name']."</td>";
                        echo"<td>".$row['Email']."</td>";
                        echo"</tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</table>";
                    echo"</div>";
                }
                $db->close();
            }

        ?>
```

**Search.php** for one textfield

```
            <?php
        $dbHost = 'localhost';
        $dbUsername = 'bobo';
        $dbPassword = 'rodnik';
        $dbName = 'training';

        //connect with the database
        $db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

        //get search term
        $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

        //get matched data from customer table

        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE Company_Name LIKE '".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY Company_Name ASC"); //Starts with


        while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data[] = $row['Company_Name'];
        }
        //return json data
        echo json_encode($data);
        ?>
```

The problem is I want to use a single search php file to cater for other queries. 
For example:

- If a word is typed in the Contact textfield, the query will be
  "SELECT * FROM Contact...."
- If a word is typed in the Customer    textfield, the query will be
  "SELECT * FROM Customer...."

Both index.php and search.php were modified to achieve this.

**Modified part in index.php**

A jQuery variable, component_name was defined. **On change** from the **index.php** file, the customer texfield will send the variable to **search.php** file using a POST method so that it can be identified and used for query purposes.

The contact textfield can be either in the same form in the index.php file or in another php file.

```
             <script>
              $(function() {
                $( "#customer" ).autocomplete({
                    var component_name= "customer";

                    source: "../phpfiles/search.php",
                    minLength: 1, 
                    change: function(event, ui) 
                    {
                        $.post("../phpfiles/search.php", data{post_data: component_name});
                    }
                });
              });
          </script>
```

**Modified search.php**

```
        <?php
    $dbHost = 'localhost';
    $dbUsername = 'bobo';
    $dbPassword = 'rodnik';
    $dbName = 'training';
    //connect with the database
    $db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);
    //get search term
    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
    //get matched data from skills table

    $query="";
    if($_POST['post_data']=="customer")
    {

        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE Company_Name LIKE '".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY Company_Name ASC"); //Starts with
        while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $data[] = $row['Company_Name'];
        }

        //return json data
        echo json_encode($data);
    }


    ?>
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

I used these links for the jquery-ui and jquery api parts:

- api.jquery.com
- jqueryui.com

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you using this when editing the resulting Search on your index.php? It's a little confusing the way you have presented it. I would use a class selector to select both text fields. Then in your `source` you can determine which field is being used and perform a search based on that.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little complicated ad I hope it helps. Your example does not provide any example data or schema to your DB, so I had to make a number of guesses. You'll need to adjust.

Consider if you have different input fields, you could have:

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <form id="customer_report_request" name="customer_report_request" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th colspan='2'>Search Customer</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Customer: </label>
          <input class="entry-field" name="customer" id="customer" value='' required>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label>Submit: </label>
          <input value="Send" name="send_customer_request" type="submit" id="send_customer_request">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Contact: </label>
          <input class="entry-field" name="contact" id="contact" value='' required>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label>Submit: </label>
          <input value="Send" name="send_customer_request" type="submit" id="send_ccontact_request">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(".entry-field").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, resp) {
      // determine which field we're working with
      var type = $("this").attr("id");
      // collect the entry in the field
      var term = req.term;
      // Prepare our response array
      var responses = [];
      // PErform POST Request to our Search and accept JSON results
      $.ajax({
            url: "../phpfiles/search.php",
            data: {
              t: type,
              q: term
            },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(results) {
              $.each(results, function(key, val) {
                responses.push(val);
              });
            }); resp(responses);
        },
        minLength: 1
    }
  });
  
  $("#customer_report_request").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("#customer").val().length) {
      // perform POST to a PHP search for that specific customer details
    } else {
      // performn a post to a PHP search for that specific contact details
    }
    // populate result DIV on page with resulting data from POST
  });
});
```

**PHP: search.php**

```
<?php
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'bobo';
$dbPassword = 'rodnik';
$dbName = 'training';
//connect with the database
$db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);
// get search query
$searchTerm = $_POST['q'];
// get search type
$searchType = $_POST['t'];
//get matched data from customer table
if($searchType == "customer"){
    /* create a prepared statement */
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE Company_Name LIKE '?%'");
    
} else {
    /* create a prepared statement */
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE Contact_Name LIKE '?%'");
}
/* bind parameters for markers */
$stmt->bind_param("s", $searchTerm);
/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();
/* instead of bind_result: */
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($searchType == "company"){
        $data[] = $row['Company_Name'];
    } else {
        $data[] = $row['Contact_Name']
    }
}
//return json data
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

So there is a lot going on. Will start with your PHP. It was vulnerable to SQL Injection, so I made use of MySQLi Prepare to protect things. We are expecting data to be posted to this script, and we're expecting to conditions: `query` and `type`. If we do not get a type, we can set defaults. Might want to add a check for `query`, but it should always have 1 character.

We get this data to our Search script using the function method for the `source` option. See more: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

> Function: The third variation, a callback, provides the most flexibility and can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete. The callback gets two arguments:
>
> - A `request` object, with a single `term` property, which refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, if the user enters "new yo" in a city field, the Autocomplete `term` will equal "new yo".
> - A `response` callback, which expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the provided `term`, and can be in any of the formats described above for simple local data. It's important when providing a custom source callback to handle errors during the `request`. You must always call the `response` callback even if you encounter an error. This ensures that the widget always has the correct state.

So with this, we can add to our `$.ajax()` call and make use of the `error` callback. Basically, we've end up sending an empty array back to `response`.

So we send a send a search term to PHP, we get JSON array data back, we pipe this into our own array to send back to `response`, and the user will get a list of results.

It's still a little clunky and that's ok if that's what you're users are used to. You can slim it down and also categorize your results. This way you can have one search field. Also once something is selected or the field is change, you can then use AJAX again to pull those details from another PHP that harvests all the data from the DB. This would result in not having to wait for the page to load again etc.

I hope this answer your question and I suspect it will raise more too. Keep searching around, there are lots of answers. Sometimes it's easier to break a big problem down into smaller single questions than to tackle the whole.